# Javascript - Online collision detection based on colours

Tags: javascript, canvas, colors, collision-detection

My game is colegame.herokuapp.com and I was wondering if I could make it so that it is impossible to go off canvas as you cannot see anyone if they are off canvas. For my players I use emoji's as to make it easier to code and less time consuming. Does anyone know how to make collision detection based off of colours? Thanks and please provide the code used for it as I am a beginner. The size of my canvas is based off of the size of the screen. It is always a square though.

Comment: You may want to provide the code you have at least attempted. Stackoverflow is not a "do my homework" site. We are here to guide and help but not provide a full solution to a problem.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to restrict the position of your player based on the size of the canvas.

Here's an example with a 100x100 world, with a 10x10 player.

Click on the black box, and use the arrow keys of your keyboard to move the "player".

```js
var canvas = document.getElementById("my-canvas");
var ctx = canvas.getContext("2d");
var playerPosition = [45, 45];

if (canvas.getContext) {
    draw();
    window.addEventListener('keydown', move, true);
}

function move(evt)
{
    switch (evt.keyCode) {
        case 37: // left
            playerPosition[0] -= 5;
            break;
        case 38: // up
            playerPosition[1] -= 5;
            break;
        case 39: // right
            playerPosition[0] += 5;
            break;
        case 40: // down
            playerPosition[1] += 5;
            break;
    }
    
    // restricting the movement of the player happens here
    if (playerPosition[0] < 0) playerPosition[0] = 0;
    if (playerPosition[0] > 90) playerPosition[0] = 90;
    if (playerPosition[1] < 0) playerPosition[1] = 0;
    if (playerPosition[1] > 90) playerPosition[1] = 90;
    
    draw();
}

function draw() {
    ctx.fillStyle = "#000000";
    ctx.fillRect(0, 0, 100, 100);
    ctx.fillStyle = "#ff0000";
    ctx.fillRect(playerPosition[0], playerPosition[1], 10, 10);
}
```

```css
#my-canvas {
  width: 100px;
  height: 100px;
}
```

```html
<canvas id="my-canvas"></canvas>
```

Comment: FYI `KeyboardEvent.keyCode` is a depreciated property, you should be using `KeyboardEvent.code` instead. For more see MDN https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/KeyboardEvent/keyCode